# Does the final keyword store variables inside methods like static?

Tags: java

Newbie to Java here. I'm in the process of porting my iPhone app to Android. From what I've read, the `final` keyword is pretty much equivalent to `static`. But does it work the same inside a method?

For example in Objective-C inside a method... `static Class aClass = [[aClass alloc] init];` wouldn't be reallocated again and it wouldn't be disposed at the end of the method.

Would something in Java inside a method like... `final Class aClass = new aClass();` act the same?

Comment: `From what I've read, the final keyword is pretty much equivalent to static` : you should throw away your Java book, `final` and `static` are like sun and moon

Comment: You'll find various semantics of `final` in Java in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027027/java-changing-value-of-final-array-element/26027048#26027048

Comment: @Dici Thanks, I guess it's less confusing that way.

Comment: Sorry, it was the wrong post, I actually thought of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348577/is-there-an-advantage-to-declaring-a-private-method-final-in-java/27348639#27348639

Comment: `final` is to `static` what potatoes are to doorways. They are *completely* different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java isn't really like `Objective C` in that respect, and `final` is more akin to `const` because it indicates a reference may not be altered. In your example, when the block ends the `final` variable will be eligible for garbage-collection as it is no longer reachable. I think you want a field variable something like

```
static final aClass aField = new aClass();
```

Note that Java class names start with a capital letter by convention...

```
static final MyClass aField = new MyClass();
```

Comment: Oops, that was just an oversight. I didn't include the class at all. Edited. Is there any keyword that would store them or do I just need to store it in file scope?

Comment: There is no equivalent keyword, you need them in the class scope (so it is a field).

Answer (score 4):

No. Block-local variables go out of scope when the block is exited and are logically (and usually physically) allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the meaning of Final and Static.

Final means that the value of the variable cannot be changed after its value is initially declared.

Static means a variable can be accessed and changed without needing to instantiate a class beforehand.

Perhaps the following bit of code will make this more clear.

```
public class SF1 {

static int x;
final int y = 3;
static final int z = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        x = 1;
        // works fine

        SF1 classInstance = new SF1();
        classInstance.y = 4;
        // will give an error: "The final field main.y cannot be assigned"

        z = 6;
        // will give an error: "The final field main.z cannot be assigned"

        reassignIntValue();
        // x now equals 25, even if called from the main method

        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void reassignIntValue() {
        x = 25;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your variable in class scope so you can able to access it outside of your method.

```
class ABC{

 int a;

 public void method(){
    a = 10; // initialize your variable or do any operation you want.  
 }


 public static void main(String args[]){

    ABC abc = new ABC();
    System.out.println(abc.a) // it will print a result
 }     

}
```

Comment: You can't put a raw statement outside a block, that `System.out.println(a);` won't work.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have just provided spudo code previously, but I have now edited it.